# How divide number by standard deviation of its respect group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

Hi suppose I have a dataframe as such,

```
g1 = data.frame ( 
    gene = c( "a","a","a","a","b","b"),
    value = c(1,200,3,5,0,3)
)
> g1
  gene value
1    a     1
2    a   200
3    a     3
4    a     5
5    b     0
6    b     3
```

using ddply I can generate descriptive values for each of the groups.

```
ddply(g1, c("gene"), summarise,
      N    = length(value),
      mean = mean(value),
      sd   = sd(value),
      se   = sd / sqrt(N)
)
  gene N  mean       sd       se
1    a 4 52.25 98.51354 49.25677
2    b 2  1.50  2.12132  1.50000
```

However is there way I can divide each number in the row by its respected sd? 
So the example above the first row would be 1/98.5

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate new column depending on aggregate function on group using dplyr (add summary statistics on the summary statistics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213465/how-to-calculate-new-column-depending-on-aggregate-function-on-group-using-dplyr)

Comment: Use `dplyr::mutate` instead of `summarise`. It's worth noting that `plyr` was retired in favor of `dplyr` a while back

Answer (score 0):

```
> g2<-group_by(g1,gene) %>% mutate(zscore = (value - mean(value))/sd(value))
> g2
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   gene [2]
  gene  value zscore
  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a         1 -0.520
2 a       200  1.50 
3 a         3 -0.500
4 a         5 -0.480
5 b         0 -0.707
6 b         3  0.707
```

i know this is not the exact question you asked, but you can get there from here...

Comment: yeh thanks I think that works `data.frame ( group_by(g1,gene) %>% mutate(x = value /sd(value) ) )`

Comment: "A z-score (aka, a standard score) indicates how many standard deviations a value is from the mean."  what are you using value/sd for?

Comment: I'm trying to fix  heteroscedasticity in my regression by using these as weights.  When I plotted residual I realized from the original model I realized that the variance was inconsistent between groups. I'm not sure but I think this might work!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97832/how-do-you-find-weights-for-weighted-least-squares-regression . I will throw this link in as a reference for dealing with regression in presence of heteroscedasticity, which means your residuals from the regression are not normally distributed. The link specifically addresses how to find the weights for weighted least squares

Comment: thanks that was a great link.  I think its a really good lead.  The answer also posted a few examples to another link.  this is helpful